# Windows 10 TPM Firmware Update for Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-10, security, tpm, windows-10-v1803

I just updated my OS to windows 10 pro version 1803. In Windows Defender, I now see a warning telling me a firmware update is needed for my security processor (TPM). There is a *learn more* link that takes me to a Microsoft website, but the information there is not helpful at all. I basically don't know how to resolve this issue, mainly because I don't know where to get the new firmware. The manufacturer of my TPM is IFX, with manufacturer version 5.0.1089.2, and specification version 2.0.

Can someone guide me on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft manufactured the device, they should provide the new firmware. [Here is the latest driver and firmware package for that model](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826), download and install it.

Comment: I would preferably like to just update this one module's firmware. Is that possible?

Comment: I downloaded KB29... which is more recent than the one Windows Update shows me. But when I install it, it installs something called *click note for Windows 8.1*. What?

Comment: **Update:** Talked to Microsoft support and they said the update has not been released for SP3. She said to wait and it will appear in Windows Update. Is this true? I've read people who have found a way to install it. Just never read how to do it!

Comment: Im sure they went to the manufacturers site that made the tpm module and got it there, I would wait for Microsoft to provide it.

Comment: "But when I install it, it installs something called click note for Windows 8.1. What?" That update is for W8.1 and 10, evidently there are some notes for W8 install which you can ignore.